# Read from FileChannel with java nio

Tags: java, string, io, nio, java-io

Can you show me a simple example to read from a file named **example.txt** and put all contents into a string in my java program using **java NIO**?

Following is what I'm using for the moment:

```
FileChannel inChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(file),StandardOpenOption.READ);
CharBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(1024).asCharBuffer();
while(inChannel.read(buf)!=-1) {
    buf.flip();
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        //append to a String
        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use straight java-nio? Because being this a common operation, in most cases you better using a utility class.

Comment: it is just an exercise to understand how java nio works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static String readFile(File f, int bufSize) {
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(f),StandardOpenOption.READ);
    char[] ca = new char[bufSize];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufSize);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(rbc.read(bb) > -1) {
        CharBuffer cb = bb.asCharBuffer();
        cb.flip();
        cb.get(ca);
        sb.append(ca);
        cb.clear();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You could do without the middle man buffer `ca` if writing char by char is acceptable performance wise. In which case you could simply `sb.append(cb.get())`.

Comment: accordind to eclipse `The method read(ByteBuffer) in the type ReadableByteChannel is not applicable for the arguments (CharBuffer)`